# Redis not killing idle connections

Tags: redis

When checking connected clients with `client list`, I have a ton of connections like:

`id=237579 addr=xxx:42754 fd=2558 name= age=1485937 idle=1485936 flags=N db=0 sub=2 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe`

When I do `config get timeout` the timeout value is `"86400"`

The age and idle of these are above this timeout, any idea why these would still be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the last issued command for that client is `subscribe`

From http://redis.io/topics/clients:

> Note that the timeout only applies to normal clients and it does not apply to Pub/Sub clients, since a Pub/Sub connection is a push style connection so a client that is idle is the norm.